# Перекласти Junk Food

Tags: переклад, from-english

Як перекласти *Junk Food*. Нездорова їжа?

Comment: [Очевидні варіанти](https://translate.google.com/#en/uk/junk%20food) дивилися? Якщо вони не підходять, то — чим?

Comment: @bytebuster GoogleTranslate це робот, От коли лінгвісти наповнять ту базу перекладів - тоді можна й приводити як приклад.

Comment: Під очевидними варіантами мається на увазі [make your own search prior to asking](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Зовсім не обов'язково, щоб це був Google Translate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[«Загальний народний англійсько-український словник» на E2U](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=junk+food&dicts=1&highlight=on) (не авторитет, але інших немає):

- нездорова їжа;
- неповноцінні харчі;
- їжа з «порожніми» калоріями;
- помийна їжа.

Google Translate (ну зовсім не авторитет, але):

- шкідлива їжа;
- нездорова їжа.

Пряма транслітерація:

- джанк-фуд ([Google](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%B4%22&lr=lang_uk), [лейпцизький корпус 2014](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%B4));
- джанкфуд ([Google](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%84%D1%83%D0%B4%22&lr=lang_uk)).

Хоча **«шкідлива їжа»** і **«нездорова їжа»** є радше гіперонімами, аніж позначають конкретно [Junk food](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junk_food) — тим не менш я би обрав саме їх, бо вони найближчі з інтуїтивно зрозумілих.

«*Їжа з „порожніми“ калоріями*» намагається найточніше передати зміст поняття, в тому числі калькуючи російське «[пустые калории](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)» — але доки я не прочитав обґрунтування цього терміну, я не розумів, що це. Хоча в [Google](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%96+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%97%22) «порожні калорії» трапляються (і навіть у [Google Books](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%96+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%97%22)).

«*Помийна їжа*» особисто в мене викликає зовсім інші асоціації; в Google трапляється здебільшого лише як дослівний переклад (пояснення) для «junk food», хоча є й [декілька окремих траплянь](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%97%D0%B6%D0%B0%22+-%22junk+food%22+-%22%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%B4%22+-%22%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%84%D1%83%D0%B4%22).

«*Неповноцінні харчі*», як на мене, надто широкий гіперонім; це радше пояснення, а не переклад.

Також слід зазначити, що в наших реаліях [фаст-фуд/фастфуд](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%B4) часто асоціюється з джанк-фудом — в деяких контекстах (наприклад, художніх) можливо використати саме його в цьому сенсі.

Comment: Я б додав +50 якби міг за термін *гіперонім* ))

Comment: Також можна перекладати як "фастфуд". Це іншомовне слово дуже добре закріпилося в українській і є абсолютним еквівалентом слова `junk food`.

Comment: @improbable, я в кінці про це сказав; тільки я не думаю, що є абсолютним еквівалентом.

Comment: @Sasha Коли я проходив курси англійської мови, ми читали статтю із воркбука, котра називалася "Junk Food" і там якраз вся сторінка була в їжі з Mcdonalds, Burger King etc. Тоді ми перекладали це слово саме так. Погоджуюся, це не фаст-фуд в 100% випадках, але, зазвичай, це те, що мають на увазі нейтів спікери, коли використовують це слово. Залишилося придумати або знайти український аналог слова `фаст-фуд` =В

Answer (score 10):

Пропоную розглянути "[пусте](http://sum.in.ua/s/pustyj) [їдло](http://sum.in.ua/s/jidlo)" і можливі варіації "пустоїдло", "пусте-їдло".

`пусте` подається у СУМ-11 з-поміж іншого у такому значенні:

> 3. перен. Позбавлений змісту, убогий змістом; беззмістовний, порожній.

`їдло` - це, вочевидь, [калька зі слова у чеській мові для позначення їжі](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/j%C3%ADdlo). Зауважте, що деякі чеські слова звучать на українському грунті дещо згрубіло, але в той самий час досить точно відображають суть, як то:

- для позначення транспортного засобу - [возидло](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vozidlo)
- для позначення плавзасобу - [плавидло](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plavidlo)
- для позначення театру - [дивадло](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divadlo)

Останнім часом найбільш вживаним слово `їдло` було в українському перекладі серіалу "Альф".

Тож вважаю, запропоновані мною варіанти можна вважати майже дослівним перекладом, який досить точно передає суть `Junk Food` у більшості контекстів.

Comment: А мені подобається :). Хоча в моїй підсвідомості викликає когнітивний дисонанс сполука слова «пустий» з тим, що насправді містить **калорії** (тобто виконує основне призначення їжі) — але ж часи змінилися, питання «дотягнути до завтра» вже не стоїть, і тепер правильна їжа має не лише забезпечувати енергією на короткий період часу, а й дозволяти бути здоровим у довгій перспективі. Не робить цього ⇒ пуста. А «їдло» підкреслює ставлення людей. +1.

Comment: Реклама "Фрузі", яка теж вживала *їдло*, була пізніше за "Альфа".

Comment: +1 за їдло. Пусте, порожнє чи шкідливе - то вже друге питання :)

Answer (score 1):

**Сміттєїжа.** Цей термін вже активно вживається:

- [Сміттєїжа: Супрун розповіла про отруєння, атеросклероз і ботулізм через шаурму](https://ukranews.com/ua/news/636271-suprun-rozpovila-pro-shaurmu-i-yiyi-shkodu-dlya-zdorov-ya)
- [Як зберегти здоров'я під час подорожі — пояснює біологиня](http://nrcu.gov.ua/news.html?newsID=89737)

  > *Сміттєїжа*, яку нам пропонують кафе аеропортів та вокзалів, є шкідливою, а возити із собою контейнер із салатом та кашою мало хто стане.
- [Супер-пупер-фуди. Зроблено в Україні, і чи вони таки супер](https://medium.com/@DariaProkopyk/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%96-%D1%96-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80-6a6030b7deb0)

  > Кожен продукт, що не припадає під категорію “*сміттєїжа*”, чимось корисний по-своєму. Тому, що різноманітніше наше харчування, то краще.

Цікаво, що перший коментар до статті [Burger King та KFC захоплюють ринок України](http://kava.lviv.ua/ua/news/4426/~burger-king-ta-kfc-zakhoplyuyut-rynok-ukrainy) датований 1 листопада 2011 року вже містить це слово, тобто зародився цей переклад давно.

> Краще б у Львові її не було, цієї сміттєїжі.